# Losing context root when navigating to root in Vaadin application with Payara Server

Tags: java, vaadin, payara, vaadin-flow

Im using Vaadin flow 13.0.4, and im using payara 5.191 for the server. The context root for my application is /TestApp/ (full link is localhost:8080/TestApp/) I have 2 views in my application, View1 with Route("") and View2 with Route("View2"). When i navigate from View1 to View2 via the following code:

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate("View2");
```

it works fine and my url is localhost:8080/TestApp/View2, but when i navigate back to View1 via :

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate("");
```

the view is loaded properly, but the url is localhost:8080/ without the TestApp context root. Any idea why this is happening? This is probably a payara thing, but im not sure what is doing it, if any files or any more of my code is required, tell me in the comments, and i'll make a quick MWE.

Comment: It seems like you are experiencing this  issue [UI.navigate(...) removes context path from URL](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5434) ... Did it work before on some other version like 13.0.0? I would also recommend to comment on the ticket with the info, that issue is reproducable in 13.0.4

Comment: i think the last time it worked was in 13.0.1? Been happening for a while, just been offputting it. But its still annoying, because refreshing the page, throws a 404 ofcourse.

Comment: Try to downgrade for now to that version, until bug is fixed . But ,of course, it's annoying. Also, comment on the issue there . Flow team really takes into account bug reports and their  severity